# addClass and removeClass jQuery issues (SetTimeout does not work inside loop)

Tags: javascript, jquery, while-loop, settimeout

First time posting.  I am having trouble getting some code to work.  I am creating a Simon Says game and I am trying to achieve adding and removing a class to an array of items using the setTimeout function in jQuery.  When I use the addClass and removeClass methods outside of a while loop by themselves, it will change the class and then change it back.  However, when I put it inside of a while loop (so I can loop through the previous Simon Says button sequence) the class is added to the element, but then does not change back after the allotted time on the setTimeout function.

Here is the code:

```js
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  gamePattern.push(randomNumber);
  // $("#" + buttonColors[randomNumber]).addClass("pressed");
  // setTimeout(function() {
  //   $("#" + buttonColors[randomNumber]).removeClass("pressed");
  // }, 500);

  var ticker = 0;
  while (ticker < gamePattern.length) {
    console.log("#" + buttonColors[gamePattern[ticker]]);
    $("#" + buttonColors[gamePattern[ticker]]).addClass("pressed");
    setTimeout(function() {
      $("#" + buttonColors[gamePattern[ticker]]).removeClass("pressed");
    }, 500);
    ticker += 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">

<h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
<div class="container">
  <div lass="row">

    <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">

    </div>

    <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">

    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">

    <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">

    </div>
    <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">

    </div>

  </div>

</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The commented portion is the code that actually works to change the element and then change it back after 500ms.  Inside the while loop, the console.log message does display the correct information.

Comment: Did you come up with a conclusion?

Answer (score 0):

### What's happening?

Actually the problem is `while` loop will not wait for [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout). So it will increment the `ticker` before `setTimeout` handler gets executed. Since your `gamePattern` is an array of one element when `ticker` gets increment the result of `gamePattern[ticker]` will be `undefined` so it won't find such an element in your DOM.

### How to fix this?

In order to fix this, You need to set a different time delay for each to execute, then we need to use a simple [`closure`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) to hold the current value of `ticker` and then pass it to the `setTimeout` correctly. In your particular case function needs to be executed initially so we need to use an [anonymous `function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Function).

So your final code should be something like this:

```js
var buttonColors = ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow"];
var gamePattern = [];

function nextSequence() {
  var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 4);
  gamePattern.push(randomNumber);
  // $("#" + buttonColors[randomNumber]).addClass("pressed");
  // setTimeout(function() {
  //   $("#" + buttonColors[randomNumber]).removeClass("pressed");
  // }, 500);

  var ticker = 0;

  while (ticker < gamePattern.length) {
    $("#" + buttonColors[gamePattern[ticker]]).addClass("pressed");
    console.log("#" + buttonColors[gamePattern[ticker]]);
    (function(ticker) {
      setTimeout(function() {
        $("#" + buttonColors[gamePattern[ticker]]).removeClass("pressed");
        console.log("#" + buttonColors[gamePattern[ticker]]);
      }, 500 * ticker)
    })(ticker++)
  }
}

nextSequence();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Simon</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="level-title">Press A Key to Start</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div lass="row">

      <div type="button" id="green" class="btn green">
      </div>

      <div type="button" id="red" class="btn red">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">

      <div type="button" id="yellow" class="btn yellow">
      </div>
      <div type="button" id="blue" class="btn blue">
      </div>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Javascript -->
  <script src="game.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Wow!  That's complex.  No wonder I couldn't figure it out.  Thanks, very much!!!

Comment: @EricMichel  I'm glad it helps, you can mark it as an answer by using the grey mark (tick) icon beside the answer. For more information, you can read [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).